# 14.04: gnome-color-manager - fails to connecto 'instrument'

Tags: color-management, gnome-color-manager

When using:
`System Settings > Color > (select display) > Calibrate`
... to attempt to do calibration on a display I consistently get:

> gnome-color-manager new_disprd() failed with 'Instrument access Failed'

... displayed in a dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the 'instrument' in qestion is a Datacolor Spyder 4, try this:

```
$ cd ~/.local/share/ArgyllCMS
$ ls -l *.bin
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hannu hannu 1968 aug 22 15:48 spyd4cal.bin
$ mv spyd4cal.bin spyd4cal.bin_
```

Then restart `System Settings > Color > (select display) > Calibrate`

*From what I understand this is the calibartion data for the 'instrument' that has been read out of the device itself. It seems this does get corrupted of some reason, and removing it launches a new readout - which corrects the problem.*